# exclude columns from dataset in GCP AutoML Tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I imported a data set with more than 50 columns, I wanted to test adding and removing columns and then run "train" a few times. How can I remove the columns after importing a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I found that we can exclude columns in before the "train" step.

Answer (score 0):

As May - 2020 when you go to the next step "train", then in the "train" section you can select the columns

[image]