# Exclude columns from dataset in GCP AutoML Tables using REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

A similar question to the one asked here - [exclude columns from dataset in GCP AutoML Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859376/exclude-columns-from-dataset-in-gcp-automl-tables) but a little more complex

I am using AUTOML Tables, but creating a CSV file from my SQL database to train the models on, and at the back end, when predictions are requested on new data submitting a CSV file and then picking up the output CSV file from a folder within a GCP bucket.

My question is, after training the model, when you are submitting new data for scoring, is it possible to programmatically pass a unique ID in the CSV that wasn't used in the training of the model, so that I can use that ID to ensure that the right scores are being assigned to the records from the batch?

Alternatively, if the schema for the trained model would require that Unique ID in order to read the prediction request CSV (as it presumably requires the same number of variables in the schema), is it possible to pass a variable (the Unique ID) in training a model, but not have this variable used in the training (as I dont want to introduce any unintended bias with the Unique ID)?

I can see where this is possible using python, but I cannot find anywhere in the REST documentation where it is possible to do using the API.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I presume that you can use [models.create](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/create) REST API method, supplying it only with the columns that will be included in the training  throughout particular AutoML Tables model metadata [form](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models#tablesmodelmetadata) (`inputFeatureColumnSpecs` field). Is it something that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Google [Cloud AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl) represents [*AutoML API REST*](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest) as a programmatic interface, accessing different ML models methods via REST HTTP calls or client libraries in popular programming languages.

In particular, for [AutoML Tables](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs) product, as I mentioned in the comment you might be able to compose `models.create` API [method](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/create), defining appropriate `TablesModelMetadata` [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models#tablesmodelmetadata) model, triggering training process on the prepared dataset.

Further discovering `TablesModelMetadata` JSON form, you can find `inputFeatureColumnSpecs` field, where you specify the table's [columns](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets.tableSpecs.columnSpecs#resource:-columnspec), on which the model suppose to be trained.

According to `inputFeatureColumnSpecs` description if no column names are stored within this field, then **all primary table's columns are used for the training and prediction input except *target_column*, *weight_column* and *ml_use_column***.